# Changing default accessibility behaviour of UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, accessibility

I am trying to implement accessibility in a `UICollectionView` which is in a viewController along with 2 other UI elements.

There are 3 cells in a collectionView(horizontal scrolling) and second cell is visible currently.

Now, I click on first UI element and if I navigate to collectionView through accessibility, then it takes me back to the first cell instead of the second cell(which is default behaviour).

How can I implement it in such a way that when I navigate from first UI element to collcetionView through accessibility then it comes to the last visible cell(2nd cell in this case)?

Comment: Did you create the cells in storyboard ?, if so may be the order is messed up there. Sometimes copying a cell and pasting might cause it. Delete the cells and re-create them in order and try

Answer (score 0):

#### Real world Scenario:

In a real world the user using accessibility wouldn't be tapping on views.

#### Solution:

- So use `accessibilityIncrement` and `accessibilityDecrement` to scroll through the `UICollectionView`
- When these methods are implemented, the voice over would suggest how to navigate (one finger swipe up / down).
- `accessibilityElements` is an array you can set if you want to change the order of the elements
- Also post `layoutChanged` and `screenChanged` when necessary, so that accessibility is aware of the change

#### Refer:

- Documentation - https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/SupportingAccessibility.html
- Demo: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/230/